# Sending webhooks when reward rule triggered in Branch.io

Tags: branch.io

We want to set up a referral system with branch.io, but want to track the credits with our backend system.

When a reward rule is triggered, is it possible for branch to hit our servers with a webhook?

Essentially, we want to be able to select "Reward Triggered" from the dropdown shown in the screenshot below.

The documentation (https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#referral-create-rule) mentions to that with `type = web_hook`, a webhook will be sent each time the reward rule is triggered. Example:

POST to `https://api.branch.io/v1/eventresponse`

`{
  "branch_key": "...",
  "branch_secret": "...",
  "calculation_type": 1,
  "location": 1,
  "type": "web_hook",
  "event": "Shipment Status Update",
  "metadata": {
    "web_hook_url": "http://www.example.com",
    "amount": "20",
    "bucket": "default"
  },
  "filter": {
    "qualifies_for_referral_credit": true,
    "status_update": "shipped"
  }
}`

With this setup, the webhook is triggered on every event that matches the filters. What we need is the webhook to be sent when the event is received AND a reward rule triggered.

[image: Webhook Adding Dialogue]

Answer (score 0):

Aaron from Branch here. A Reward Rule will only be triggered if you have set them up here: https://dashboard.branch.io/referrals/rules

These Reward Rules will only be triggered when the event is triggered in the same first install session. If the Reward Rule is still not being triggered, you can try removing the "type" flag from the webhook and simply create a separate webhook directly with our system for your event here: https://dashboard.branch.io/data-import-export/data-feeds/webhooks/

Comment: Thanks! If I interpret the first part of your answer correctly, then there is no way to trigger a webhook when a reward rule is triggered. Using the API to create a rule will only create a webhook, but not a reward rule.

However, the second part indicates that it should be possible. We tested creating a webhook / reward rule via the API, but as said the webhook gets triggered for every event received, not when the reward rule is triggered, with no useful referring data in the webhook: https://requestb.in/18c261m1?inspect

We only want to receive webhooks when the reward rule is triggered.